# Why the nested dictionary cannot append into list correctly?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I try to append a dictionary into a list, but I find the sub-dictionary is always keep the last one I read from CSV file(deviceProfile.csv). Does anyone know why?
Here is my CSV file.

```
name,description,primaryTable,startingAddress,boolIndex
test_name_1,1,table_1,1,1
test_name_2,2,table_2,2,2
test_name_3,3,table_3,3,3
```

Here is my python code.

```
import csv
import yaml
from pprint import pprint

resource = {
    'name': "",
    'description': "",
    'attributes':
      { 'primaryTable': "", 'startingAddress': "", 'boolIndex': "" },
}

resourceArray = []

with open("deviceProfile.csv") as f:
    myCsvDic = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in myCsvDic:
        resource['name'] = row['name']
        resource['description'] = row['description']
        resource['attributes']['primaryTable'] = row['primaryTable']
        resource['attributes']['startingAddress'] = row['startingAddress']
        resource['attributes']['boolIndex'] = row['boolIndex']
        test = resource.copy()
        resourceArray.append(test)

pprint (resourceArray)
```

And the result is

```
[{'attributes': {'boolIndex': '3',
                 'primaryTable': 'table_3',
                 'startingAddress': '3'},
  'description': '1',
  'name': 'test_name_1'},
 {'attributes': {'boolIndex': '3',
                 'primaryTable': 'table_3',
                 'startingAddress': '3'},
  'description': '2',
  'name': 'test_name_2'},
 {'attributes': {'boolIndex': '3',
                 'primaryTable': 'table_3',
                 'startingAddress': '3'},
  'description': '3',
  'name': 'test_name_3'}]
```

It is strange that **name** and **description** are appended into list correctly, but **attributes**. The **attributes** is always append the last sub-dictionary.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `copy`. by default copy is shallow copy and it will copy just level-1 elements.
you should use `deepcopy` in your case. replace `test = resource.copy()` with:

```
from copy import deepcopy

test = deepcopy(resource)
```

take a look at this [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/) for more information, or any other links that tells you about `copy(shallow and deep)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `resource` on the top outside the loop ???

```
resource = {
    'name': "",
    'description': "",
    'attributes':
      { 'primaryTable': "", 'startingAddress': "", 'boolIndex': "" },
}
```

Remove that and just change the loop to this :

```
for row in myCsvDic:
    resource = {}
    resource['name'] = row['name']
    resource['description'] = row['description']
    resource['attributes']['primaryTable'] = row['primaryTable']
    resource['attributes']['startingAddress'] = row['startingAddress']
    resource['attributes']['boolIndex'] = row['boolIndex']
    resourceArray.append(resource)
```